# Error: spawn C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin ENOENT

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, dashboard

[create new angular project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IStD0.png)

When I create a new angular project by command ng new dashboard  my node version v18.12.0 and npm 8.19.2
I got this problem
How can I solve it ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create it in your Java install's bin folder. Does this happen when you try to create it in a different folder? Like perhaps a subfolder of the path you have at the very bottom of your screenshot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.